# Qt 5.9.0 to 5.9.4 work fine, but Qt 5.9.5 and 5.9.6 have issues

Tags: qt, qt3d

I'm playing around with this repo: https://github.com/qt-labs/qt3d-editor

My observation:

1. When using Qt 5.9.0, 5.9.1, 5.9.2, 5.9.3 and 5.9.4, the application can import files, like STL.
2. But with Qt 5.9.5 and 5.9.6 the application **cannot** import any file, it gets stuck in import process and never finishes importing. Also, the same issue happens when working with Qt 5.11.

I assume it might be related to Qt3D module. The [5.9.5 change log for Qt3D](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qt3d.git/tree/dist/changes-5.9.5/?h=v5.9.5) mentions that only minor code improvements are done. Can anybody give a *hint* why this is happening?

---

The screen shot of import button getting stuck is shown below:

[image: screen shot of import button getting stuck]

Comment: Run the app under a debugger to find out what it's doing when it appears to be stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested with Qt 5.11.2 and it works fine. Take a look at this:

[Importing objects in Qt3D doesn't work but there's not error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52697782/importing-objects-in-qt3d-doesnt-work-but-theres-not-error-message)